# AWS EC2 - The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance set up as a gaming server, which works fine, but I want to change to a new instance type (from c5n.xlarge to m5zn.xlarge), which produces the error in the title when I try to start the instance.

I have created another instance in the same VPC with the same settings (as far as I can tel), and this one launches fine.

Instances are both:

Region: Sydney
AMI: Windows Server 2019 base
Storage: EBS 250GB

I am unsure exactly what information might be required to solve this, but I have checked every configuration setting I can find, and it seems identical.

Comment: It may be there are no m5zn.xlarge instances available in that availability zone or region.

Comment: @ceejayoz Wow, you are correct! I was not aware that some instances may not be available in specific AZ's within a region. It looks like 2a does not support this instance type, but 2b and 2c do. THANK YOU! Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: You're very welcome. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular error can indicate a couple of things, but most frequently it means that Availability Zone lacks capacity to start one of that specific types of instance. This is more common with the larger or more specialized instances like the big multi-GPU stuff used for machine learning.

Further details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ts-as-instancelaunchfailure.html#ts-as-instancelaunchfailure-3